# javascript name vs ID

Tags: javascript, xhtml, standards

As far as I know there are two ways to get the value from a textbox either

```
document.formName.textboxName.value;
```

or

```
document.getElementbyId('textboxId').value;
```

As I understand using form name would mean I have less code to write, as name can be used for posting data and getting the value (apart from using ajax). As where if I was just posting using a standard form I would use `name` to post but I cannot use `id` ?

e.g. in php I would use

```
$_POST['texboxName'];
```

If I where to have and ID on the textbox I cannot get the value using php ?

Which is the standard recommened way of doing this, and is using `name` browser friendly? Links if possible please, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ultimate guide in this is the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/).

Things that stand out there:

- `id` is valid for any HTML element, while `name` only applies to a select few (`a`, `input`, `textarea` and maybe a few others).
- An `input` (and `textarea`) element **requires** the `name` to be set if you want it to be submitted.

Comment: @Vilx - Am aware this is slightly old but was wondering what you mean by "share the same namespace"

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Thank you for pointing this out to me. I've been mistaken. The namespace sharing thing is [only valid for anchor elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id). The link explains it better, but in a nutshell, when using the `#` in the URL to jump to a specific anchor, it looks at both `id` and `name` attributes to determine which anchor to scroll to. If there were two different anchors where one's `id` was equal to the other's `name`, the browser would get confused. So the spec makes this invalid.

Comment: Don't forget that `getElementsByName()` returns a live query: every time you access an element in the array returned, or even just its length, the DOM will be queried again. 
That's going to be super-slow!
`getElementById` performance is always better - one more reason to use `id` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 4):

The `name` attribute is used during submitting the form, i.e. to create a name-value pair that will be processed to the server. The `id` attribute is used to locate and element in the DOM. Usually the name is used only on the form elements

References:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

I typically use both.  As you mentioned, `name` is useful for using the data via JavaScript and also once it has been submitted.  Feel free to use additional characters in the `name` as needed: I tend to use `[]`s in my names when the input will be used in an array server-side.

The `id` attribute can be used for accessing the element via JS/the DOM.  It is also used by `<label>`'s `for` attribute.  If you do this with checkboxes, for example, clicking on the label will cause the box to become checked.  That's a big plus for usability.

Answer (score 1):

I consider it good practice to have a name **and** id for each form element. The reason being that if you want to add labels, or styling via sytlesheets (which you should be doing), then it makes sense to have both.

As for accessing it with javascript: the better way would be to go with the element's id, becuase if you change the name of the form everything breaks. This does not happen when you use the id.

Comment: Most JavaScript activity dealing with a form, though, is initiated from within the form (from button and field events or from the onsubmit event of the form itself) so using `this.form` or `this` from the caller has no ambiguity. Note, too, that a "field" may involve more than one element, so checking values by name rather than by id is often a necessity (think radio buttons and checkboxes).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using IDs, as the "function" (i.e.: what you're trying to achieve) of your code isn't tied up with in the semantics.  For me, .GetElementById('myid') stands out more, and is more readable that just having "myid" scattered among the code.  Plus you can more easily rename elements.  That's my 2p worth!