# input string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, input

Short question

**QUESTION**

How can I access the string value `"2013-10-20"` from the input in HTML to show it in JavaScript?

**HTML**

```
<input name="DateStart" class="inputPanel" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="2013-10-20">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script javascript="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert("Value: " + ???)
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one input with the name DateStart(use id's):

```
alert("Value: " + document.getElementsByName('DateStart')[0].value);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is in a form, and there is only one form in the document, you can access it like:

```
alert(document.forms[0].DateStart.value);
```

If the form has a name you can use:

```
alert(document.forms['formName'].DateStart.value);
```

or if you like being long–winded:

```
alert(document.forms['formName'].elements['DateStart'].value);
```

or if the name is also a valid identifier (i.e. a name you could also use as a variable name)

```
alert(document.forms.formName.DateStart.value);
```

or even:

```
alert(document.formName.DateStart.value);
```

Or an ID:

```
alert(document.getElementById('formId').DateStart.value);
```

Or using the *querySelector* interface:

```
alert(document.querySelector('input[name="DateStart"]').value);
```

Lots of ways to skin that cat.

Comment: Answers like this not only answers OPs question but also helps others to learn

Answer (score 2):

From the current code you can use [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

```
var dateStart = document.getElementsByName('DateStart')[0];
alert("Value: " + dateStart.value);
```

But it's advisable and a [best practice to add Id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute) on DOM element and using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) in JavaScript to retrieve DOM element. (take a look at [name vs id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936249/javascript-name-vs-id))

HTML

```
<input id="DateStart" name="DateStart" class="inputPanel" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="2013-10-20">
```

JavaScript

```
var dateStart = document.getElementById('DateStart');
alert("Value: " + dateStart.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say like bellow

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('inputPanel')[0].value);
```

if this is first element which has class inputPanel.